# Combining two shapefiles into third shapefile in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

Suppose I have two shapefiles (A and B). Each contain 200 polygons. There are 150 polygons that are common i.e same polygons in both shapefiles but 50 polygons in each shapefile are unique. I want combine both these shapefiles into third shapefile (C) containing 250 polygons. 150 (common) + 50 (shapefile A) + 50 (shapefile B). I have tried the merge tool but the output shapefile has less number of polygons.

Comment: There are many potential ways to accomplish this. What have you tried? What error or problem did you encounter?  Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: @Vince question edited

Comment: Merge should result in 350 features. What exactly did you do?

Comment: @FelixIP I provided my two shapefiles as input datasets in merge tool.

Comment: Set environment extent to "union of input". Use tool(!) select layer by location (invert selection)  using any as target, e.g. layer A.This will select unique in A. Merge A and B.